# Как сделать пунктирные линии в swing, не получается

Tags: java, swing

Как сделать пунктирные линии в swing?
пытаюсь сделать пунктирный дом

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Paint extends JFrame {
    public Paint () {
        super();
        setSize(300, 300);
        setVisible(true); 
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawRect(30, 300, 300, 100);
        g.drawLine(30, 300, 180, 250);
        g.drawLine(180, 250, 330, 300);
        g.drawRect(250, 350, 50, 50);
        g.drawRect(80, 330, 100, 50);
        g.drawLine(80, 355, 180, 355);
        g.drawLine(130, 330, 130, 380);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Paint();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html

Comment: там невозможно разобраться

Comment: что конкретно не понятно? там есть примеры кода и описание..